# Compare two element in same table and return difference/missing data

Tags: mysql

How to compare two IDs from same table and get difference/missing data ?

I have form for current product($current_id) where i display data from X product($id).

Data look like : name1 name2 name3

Than you can select to insert some of this data for current product($current_id) (for example: name1 name2 )

Than you have 2 records in oc_product_option_value
(oc_option_value_description hold names , oc_product_option_value hold ids and more)

$id data = name1 name2 name3

$current_id data = name1 name2

Later one if you come back to current product($current_id) and you pull same X product data($id) have to display only data = name3

How to compare that to get this result ?

```
public function getInfo($id, $current_id){

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT
                    oc_product_option_value.*,
                    oc_option_value_description.name
                    oc_product_option_value
                    LEFT JOIN oc_option_value_description ON (oc_product_option_value.option_value_id = oc_option_value_description.option_value_id)
                    WHERE product_id = '" . $id . "'");

}
```

Comment: could you add an example of the kind of result you would expect?

Comment: At the moment the code will return data: name1, name2, name3 than you can select only name1 and name2 to be inserted for $current_id so the different records between $id and $current_id will be name3 . I need to compare $id record and $current_id record to get different data but both are in same table

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that you have 2 tables. `oc_product_option_value` and `oc_option_value_description`. This confuses me somewhat.

Comment: Sorry value_description hold the names and option_value hold Ids and other stuff .

Comment: Why don't you use PHP to query only if `$id != $current_id`? Maybe I still haven't understood what you mean.

Comment: It is not clear to me how you want to compare, do you just want to read the two rows and compare the result using php or should it be done in sql. Maybe you could add some sample data and expected output to better describe your question

Comment: @YuKo how this $id != $current_id will happen  ?

Comment: hope so topic is look more understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done this with additionally query and small php code , did not found way to do whole thing with one query and without php

```
$masterProduct = $this->model_catalog_product->getMatrakOptionsMasterProduct($id);
$currentProduct = $this->model_catalog_product->getMatrakOptionsCurrentProduct($current_id);

$data['options'] = array();
$current = array_column($currentProduct, 'name');
foreach($masterProduct as $value){
if(!in_array($value['name'], $current)){
    $data['options'][] = $value;
}
}
```

and both querys

```
public function getMatrakOptionsMasterProduct($id){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT
                    oc_product_option_value.*,
                    oc_option_value_description.name
                    FROM oc_product_option_value
                    LEFT JOIN oc_option_value_description ON (oc_product_option_value.option_value_id = oc_option_value_description.option_value_id)
                    WHERE product_id = '" . $id . "'");
}


public function getMatrakOptionsCurrentProduct($current_id){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT
                oc_product_option_value.*,
                oc_option_value_description.name
                FROM oc_product_option_value
                LEFT JOIN oc_option_value_description ON (oc_product_option_value.option_value_id = oc_option_value_description.option_value_id)
                WHERE product_id = '" . $current_id . "'");
}
```